# PHP code to check for a variable if it is contained in a MySQL column?

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL I have under the table `used` where I save the make, model, price of a car and there is a column named `car_parts` for the extras like gps system, air bags.

This column saves the values from many checkboxes in this format `a value, b value, f value, g value`.

In my page I have a search form, where the user select from dropdown menus some values (like model and price) and through checkboxes some car parts. As I said the car parts are saved in the column `car_parts`.

This is how I constructed my query, since I allow the user to submit the form with some values empty:

```
$conditions = array();
if (!empty($colour)) $conditions[] = "colour = '".mysql_real_escape_string($colour)."'";
...
...
...
$conditionString = "WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $conditions);
```

My thought is that I need to have the checkboxes with different names like

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="cruisecontrol" value="Cruise Control"> Cruise Control
```

and make use of the  `$_POST["cruisecontrol"];` in the database.

My question is how can the `Cruise Control` or any others, to be checked if these values are contained into the `car_parts` `a,d,Cruise Control,j,t,r` values and construct the query?

Comment: Surely you could use a combination of php and jQuery to set the checkbox `checked` attribute? That is, after you've queried your table for the values?

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you're storing the information in the car_parts field. But I think the LIKE clause may be your friend here. Say the user checked 2 boxes these will be set in your post array. I would have the check boxes an array of post values like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="cruisecontrol" />
<input type="checkbix" name="options[]" value="radio" />
```

Then you can grab the options values and use them in your query.. supposeing you want a car with all checked options and both options are checked...

```
$whereClause =  "WHERE `car_parts` LIKE '%".implode("%' AND LIKE '%",$_POST[options])."%'"
```

should produce something like

```
WHERE `car_parts` LIKE '%cruisecontrol%' AND LIKE '%radio%'
```

This will return results where car_parts contains both cruise control and radio.

Hope that helps. Also don't forget to sanitize the data before feeding it to your query!